# Pointer to memory

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm learning C and have some problems whit pointers.
I'm triying to print the memory slot for every declared variable, but when I declare the pointer for a Char[], it just does not work.

Here's my code:

```
int main () {
    char a[3]; // this variable is my problem
    int b;
    float c;
    char d;
    int e=4;

    char *pachar; //A char type variable for the pointer.
    int *paint;
    float *pafloat;
    char *pacharr;
    int *paintt;

    pachar = &a; // when I try to assign the memory to the pointer, it shows a Warning message.
    paint = &b;
    pafloat = &c;
    pacharr = &d;
    paintt = &e;


    printf("%p \n",pachar);
    printf("%p \n",paint);
    printf("%p \n",pafloat);
    printf("%p \n",pacharr);
    printf("%p \n",paintt);

    return(0);
}
```

This is the warning message. Am I doing something wrong?

> "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: Cast the pointers to `void*` before passing to `std::printf`.

Comment: His problem is with the assignment, not `printf`.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers! You might want to see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/2679626).

Comment: Use `char (*pachar)[] = &a;`.

Comment: @thelink2012 Decay does not happen when the array is the operand of the address-of operator, as it is in this example

Answer (score 5):

You declared `a` as an array of `char`:

```
char a[3];
```

Name `a` represents an array, which can be *interpreted* as a pointer to the initial element of the array. Therefore you do not need `&` when you assign `a` to a pointer:

```
pachar = a;
```

When you take an address of `a` in `&a` expression, you get a pointer to an array of three characters. Trying to assign a pointer-to-an-array to a pointer-to-char triggers compiler warning.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of taking the address of `a`, you could take the address of the first element. The address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.

```
pachar = &a[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[3], *pachar;
pachar = a;

printf("Address = %u\n", a); // Base address of the Array. "&a" not required.

printf("Address = %u\n", &a[0]); // Address of the first element.

printf("Address = %u\n", pachar);// Address of the first element.

printf("Address = %u\n", pachar + 0); // Pointer Arithmetic ...

printf("Address = %u\n", pachar + 1); // a[1] is equivalent to pachar + 1

printf("Address = %u\n", &a[1]); // Similar to the above.
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow ... mind explaining why there is a '-1' vote ... ?